# Dismiss not working in one of two Swift UI Views

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am converting my UIKit app to SwiftUI.  The basic structure of the app is - TableView -> Simpler Table View -> Single View1 -> Single View2.
I have converted the last to "Single View"s to SwiftUI, but am experiencing strange behavior when I try to dismiss Single View1. I am using the same approach to show each view, but here's a simplified version of it -

```
struct View2: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var cardImage : UIImage
    var eventName : String
    var eventDate : String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image(uiImage: cardImage)
                 .resizable()
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Text(verbatim: eventName)
                Text(verbatim: eventDate)
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle.fill")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                } .padding(20)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

and a simplified view of View1:

```
struct ViewAnEventView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    let eventName: String
    let eventDate: String
    let cardFront: UIImage
    let cardBack: UIImage
    
    @State var showFrontCardView = false
    @State var showBackCardView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                Text(eventName)
                Text(eventDate)
            }
            VStack{
                Button( action: {
                    self.showFrontCardView = true
                }) {
                    Image(uiImage: cardFront)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 3, height: 4), contentMode: .fit)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showFrontCardView) {
                    View2(cardImage: cardFront, eventName: eventName, eventDate: eventDate)
                }
                Button( action: {
                    self.showBackCardView = true
                    
                }) {
                    Image(uiImage: cardBack)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 3, height: 4), contentMode: .fit)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showBackCardView) {
                    View2(cardImage: cardBack, eventName: eventName, eventDate: eventDate)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .overlay(
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle.fill")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    })
                } .padding(20)
            }
        )

    }
}
```

When I press the "chevron.down.circle.fill" button on View2, it is successfully dismissed, but when I press it on View1, it does not get dismissed.

This is how I call View1

```
        let event = events[indexPath.row]
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        let yourDate = event.eventDate! as Date
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy"  //check local settings and make it match
        let myStringAsDate : String = formatter.string(from: yourDate)
        

        let cardFront = (event.cardFrontImage ?? UIImage(contentsOfFile: "frontImage"))!
        let cardBack = event.cardBackImage ?? UIImage(contentsOfFile: "backImage")
        let eventName = event.event ?? "Unknown"
        
        let viewAnEventView = ViewAnEventView(
            eventName: eventName,
            eventDate: myStringAsDate,
            cardFront: cardFront,
            cardBack: cardBack!
        )
        let viewCtrl = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(viewAnEventView))
        
        present(viewCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am at stuck, is there something I should be seeing here?

Comment: If you present view (actually, viewcontroller here)  by UIKit you have to dismiss it as well by UIKit methods. These two worlds rarely interact with each-other directly.

Comment: So how would I get viewCtrl to dismiss?  I had actually had view2 working this way in the pass ( I am slowly changing all my views to SwiftUI, starting with the furthest down the stack).